# Linear Independence of functions represented as column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone SHOW how the set infinite(countably) set E = {e_i | e_i(j) = 1 for j = i and 0 everywhere else} union {(1,1,1,1,......)} are linearly independent.

Intuitively, doesn't it seem that if one were to add -1e_i (for all i) + 1(1,1,1,1,1,...) = 0 vector?

Comment: A linear combination has only **finitely many** nonzero coefficients.

Comment: ah that clarifies everything. Thank you